# Past tense vs past participle in passive forms

Tags: verbs, past-tense, past-participles, passive-voice

For example:

```
The car is driven by my a friend of mine.
```

vs

```
The car is drove by a friend of mine.
```

Which one is correct?

Comment: Always use the past participle for passive forms.

Comment: Is this "common knowledge", or "general reference", or whatever it's called here? Does it matter?

Comment: @John Lawler General Motors?

Comment: General Motors was omnipresent during the Iraq war.

Comment: Yes; it was way after Ford's administration.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I think the question belongs on ELL, not ELU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*is drove* is just wrong.

*is driven by* is awkward.

You probably should use *is being driven by*, *was driven by*, *has been driven by*, or *had been driven by*.

Comment: As usual, context can make it less awkward-sounding: [Policeman]_You say that these are your company's vehicles. Who usually drives them? [Helper-w-enquiries]_The truck is driven by my father. The car is driven by a friend of mine. James May. He'd never break the speed limit, officer.

Comment: @Edwin: And the likelihood that the asker is in such a situation compared to one of the many situations where my suggestions would be applicable?  (And I did say *probably*)

Comment: That's better asked over on maths (where someone would say about 0.01). But I'm addressing the English connected with OP's question rather than the likely lack of idiomaticity. _is driven by_ would rarely be used.

Comment: Edwin got it right, that was the sense.